# QGIS function editor tab indents generating errors?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

i'm trying the **function editor** in QGIS 2.10.1 (windows 32 bits).

I always get "indents" error as the function editor inserts **TAB** indents instead of spaces ...

How do i solve this issue ?

Comment: Not using QGIS 2.10 at the moment but usually when I work with code, I type it in Notepad using tab indents and then copying/pasting. Not sure if this will work for you though :)

Comment: Yeah this seems to be a bug in the editor.  I will fix for the next release

Comment: thx for answer guys ... yeah, working on the code in notepad++ and then close and re-open function editor, that will do the job for the moment ...